# Wpdb query with dynamic table name

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I have a separate custom table in my database for each language I'm providing for my website. I need to select the correct table dynamically from a variable that is sent from a POST request.

First I was trying to to use $wpdb->prepare but then I read that it can't really handle the name of the table since it will force it into a string.

The other solutions that I saw looked something like this:

```
$foods = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $sanitized_search_language WHERE dbID = $sanitized_search_text", ARRAY_A);
```

That will give me the following error:

```
"<div id=\"error\"><p class=\"wpdberror\"><strong>WordPress database error:</strong> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near &#039;WHERE dbID = 719&#039; at line 1]<br /><code>SELECT * FROM  WHERE dbID = 719</code></p></div>[]"
```

I also saw the variables wrapped in curly brackets in some solutions like this:

```
$foods = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$sanitized_search_language} WHERE dbID = {$sanitized_search_text}", ARRAY_A);
```

But that is also giving me an error.

How can I select the custom table I want to query based on a dynamic variable?

Comment: What is $sanitized_search_language? It appears to be blank? Also, accepting the table name from a post request is astonishingly reckless if not done properly.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hi! Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! The value was indeed empty. Is it properly enough if I use sanitize_text_field() for the search query and limit the options to the allowed table names with an if-statement?

Comment: Whitelisting values is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will start with the question.

From the sql error output we see this `SELECT * FROM  WHERE dbID = 719`

This tells us that `$sanitized_search_language` has no value, so check it first.

Now for the BIG problem with this query!

You used `get_results` with a sql query that has variables as is, `get_results` doesn't escape the variables.

You must use `prepare` when passing variables into an sql query in order to prevent sql injections.

see [wpdb::get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/#user-contributed-notes), the first user contribution shows a great example on how to implement this

Comment: Thanks for helping! The value was indeed missing and after I fixed that part, then the dynamic query started working. Is it enough to secure this if I use sanitize_text_field and also an if statement where I check that the value is one of the allowed table names? I read elsewhere that the wpdb->prepare statement won't work for the table name (only parameter values).

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't with table name, all it does is escape values and prepares them to be a valid and injection free values. Try it, it should work. About `sanitize_text_field`, its used for xss and not to prevent sql injection

Comment: I tried it and couldn't get it to work. Also the answers in this Stack Exchange question seem to suggest it's not possible to bind a dynamic table name with the prepare statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement

Comment: Ok, so you would need to create your own filter to "prepare" the table name, if it wont play nice with dynamic table names than you'll need to do the sanitization and validation